# Proving an integral relation (isotropic function)

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

In Hansen-McDonald's book *Theory of Simple Liquids* the following relation is often used:

We want to evaluate the integral

$$\int_V f(\vec r_1, \vec r_2) d \vec r_1$$

We observe that if the function $f$ is isotropic, i.e.

$$f(\vec r_1, \vec r_2) = f(\mid \vec r_1- \vec r_2 \mid) $$

then

$$\int_V f(\vec r_1, \vec r_2) d \vec r_1 = \int_V f(\mid \vec r_1- \vec r_2 \mid) d \vec r_1 =  f(r) \ V $$

where

$$V= \int_V d \vec r$$

This makes sense to me, because if the function only depends on the distance I can choose to fix $\vec r_1$ everywhere in the volume (obtaining a volume term) and I will be left with $f(r)=f(\mid \vec r_1- \vec r_2 \mid)$.

But how can I prove the last relation in a rigorous way? I guess it must be some kind of change of variables, but I cannot figure out which one.

**Update**

This relation is used for example in equation (2.5.15):

---

[image]

---

(notice that $\rho = N/V$. Also, $g(r) \to 1$ for $r\to \infty$)

I also just found out that a similar relation, which we can write as

$$\int_V \int_V f(\mid \vec r_1-\vec r_2\mid) d\vec r_1 d\vec r_2 = V \int_V f(r) d\vec r$$

is used in equation (2.5.18-19), with the following explanation:

---

[image]

---

(notice that in this case $v(r) \to 0$ for $r \to \infty$)

It would be also nice to start by proving this in two dimensions, i.e. for

$$\int_I \int_I f(\mid x-y\mid) dx dy \ \ \text{and} \ \ \int_I f(\mid x-y\mid) dy$$

where $I$ is a closed interval, even if I'm starting to suspect (see John Barber's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836989/proving-an-integral-relation-isotropic-function/1839302#1839302)) that this result is not rigorous.

Comment: shouldn't it be $\Omega_{S_3} \int f(|r|)|r|^2d|r|?$

$|r-r'|\equiv |r|$, $\Omega_{S_3}$ volume of the unit sphere in three dimensions?

Comment: But, if I define $|\vec r-\vec r'|=r$, what does $d \vec r'$ become?

Comment: Essenitaly it should be just a change to spherical coordinates

Comment: @tired I agree with you, but could you please show that explicitly?

Comment: @valerio92 Did you mean $\rho = N/V$?

Comment: @JohnBarber Yes, of course: just corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something must be wrong here. Counterexample:

Suppose
$$
f\left(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2\right) = 
f\left(\left| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2\right|\right) = 
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{{\left|\vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2\right|}^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)
$$
for some *small* $\epsilon$. Suppose the length scale of $V$ is much larger than $\epsilon$, and consider the quantity
$$
g\left(\vec{r}_2\right) = \int_V d\vec{r}_1\, f\left(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2\right)\, .
$$
The integrand is a narrow Gaussian centered at $\vec{r}_2$. If $\vec{r}_2$ is more than several multiples of $\epsilon$ away from the boundary of $V$, then essentially all of the Gaussian is integrated over, and 
$$
g\left(\vec{r}_2\right) \approx {\left(2\pi \epsilon^2\right)}^{d/2}\, ,
$$
where $d$ is the dimensionality of the space.
If $\vec{r}_2$ is *on* the boundary of $V$, then about *half* the Gaussian is integrated over, and we have
$$
g\left(\vec{r}_2\right) \approx \frac{1}{2}{\left(2\pi \epsilon^2\right)}^{d/2}\, .
$$

These bear no resemblance to (what appears to be) the asserted relationship
$$
g\left(\vec{r}_2\right) = V\, f\left( \left| \vec{r}_2 \right| \right)\, .
$$

What section of H&M does this appear in? I've got a copy of it around here somewhere. I'm wondering if perhaps the actual relationship might be
$$
\int_V d\vec{r}_1 \int_V d\vec{r}_2\, f\left(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right)
 = V \int_V d\vec{r}_1\, f\left(\vec{r}_1\right)\, ,
$$
which should be perfectly valid so long as $f$ is sufficiently strongly peaked or localized. Since it's H&M, I would imagine that $f$ is something like $f(r) = \exp\left[-U(r)/k_B T\right]$ or $f(r) = 1 - \exp\left[-U(r)/k_B T\right]$, where $U$ is an intermolecular potential?

Response to Update:

The thing to keep in mind is that there are some assumptions implicit in H&M that are relevant here. These integral identities don't apply to just *any* radial function, but only to the sort relevant in molecular thermodynamics. This assumes that the function $f(\vec{r})$ varies on a molecular length scale $\epsilon$, and that the domain of integration $V$ is more like a macroscopic length scale. So we have a radical difference of scales here. Outside a length scale $\epsilon$, the function $f$ will typically be either zero or constant. Under these assumptions, *some* of these integral "identities" are *approximately* true.

I'm not going to get into H&M Equations (2.5.15) and (2.5.18) copied above. They depend on the precise definition of the two-particle distribution function, which is beyond the scope of a *math.stackexchange* post.

I do want to address the last part of your update. Define:
$$
g(y) = \int_I dx\,  f(x - y)\, .
$$
Here $I$ is an interval of length $L$, and we assume that $f$ is compactly supported (more or less) over an interval of length on the order of $\epsilon$, a small number. An example would be:
$$
f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)\, .
$$
By the same argument as above,
$$
g(y) = \mathrm{constant} \approx \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,  f(x)
$$
unless $y$ is within a distance of about $\epsilon$ of one of the boundaries of $I$. Thus the assertion in the original post is actually *wrong*, even for H&M-type functions, and *isn't* what is being used in the equations from H&M.

However:
\begin{align}
\int_I dy\, g(y) &\approx \int_I dy \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,  f(x) \\
&\approx L \int_I dx\, f(x) \;+\; \text{An error of order $\epsilon$}\, .
\end{align}
Here I've implicitly assumed that the domain $I$ is sufficiently "centered" that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,  f(x) \approx \int_I dx\,  f(x)\, .
$$
As long as $f$ falls off sufficiently rapidly (i.e. don't try this with particles mediated by a Coulomb potential!), we can ignore the error term, and the "double integral" identity should *approximately* hold.

Update to address Equation 2.5.15 above:

*Theory of Simple Liquids* can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uhm87WZBnxEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=theory+of+simple+liquids&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw4ePHmcTNAhWDJCYKHdItDBEQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=theory%20of%20simple%20liquids&f=false) on Google Books. The relevant page is 31.

I've gone over the steps leading to equation 2.5.15, and I don't think it makes sense as written. I'm convinced it's a typo. 2.5.15 doesn't seem to follow from 2.5.14. I think the argument of the integral in 2.5.15 is supposed to be:
$$
g^{(2)}_N(r' + r, r') = g^{(2)}_N\left(\left|r' + r - r'\right|\right) = g^{(2)}_N\left(\left|r\right|\right) = g(r)
$$
That makes much more sense to me, and leads to the desired result.

Comment: I just found out that this last relation is also present. I will add more details to my answer.

Comment: Ok, this could justify 2.5.18-19. But what about 2.5.15, which is basically the case I wrote about in my original post? Are you saying that that relation is valid only for that particular function?

Comment: I mean, it is now clear that the "single integral" relation is not always valid, but it is often used and without any explicit assumption apart from the integrand function being isotropic. If there are other hidden assumption, I wonder what they could be.

Comment: You are right, now that I look more closely it looks like there is a typo. So the first relation cannot be justified, while the second one can if the domain is sufficiently centered. Since similar arguments are often used in the book, I was convinced that that relation was used more than once, but now I think that I may have been wrong...Thank you very much!